# Computers doesn't show in WSUS

Tags: iis, wsus

I have installed WSUS and configured it is supposed to be. Made sure that the port is accessible, the GPO has been updated in all machines, also I confirmed that the policy is was applied. But I still can't see the machines on the WSUS server.
I have followed Microsft's manual: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-server-update-services/deploy/2-configure-wsus#21-configure-network-connections

But even though no luck.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem you should check:

-with network admins for the accessibility of WSUS ports

-If you are using WSUS with SSL connection ensure that clients certificates parameter under the SSL encryption parameter on the following virtual roots:
ApiRemoting30; ClientWebService; DSSAuthWebService; ServerSyncWebService: SimpleAuthWebServic is set to Ignore, check this link: https://jackstromberg.com/2013/11/enabling-ssl-on-windows-server-update-services-wsus/

-If the clients have an internet connection through a proxy make sure to add the address of the WSUS server in the exception list of the Proxy Settings